# Rectangular Object Node in Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, plantuml

Can anyone tell me how to design UML's **Object Node** in PlantUml ?
According to the [UML's v2.5 spec (section 15.2.4)](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/), **Object Nodes** are supposed to be square, while the regular and most used **Action Nodes** are squircles.

[image]

All I can find in the [PlantUml documentation](http://plantuml.com/activity.html) is how to display *all* the **Action Nodes** octagon ...

I'm working with the PlantUml's v1 activity grammar :

```
@startuml
(*) --> "First Action Node"
--> "HERE I WANT AN OBJECT NODE"
--> "Last Action Node"
--> (*)
@enduml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is only achievable with the [new Activity diagram syntax](http://plantuml.com/activity2.html) (still beta), in which you can do:

```
@startuml
start
:First Action Node;
:HERE I WANT AN OBJECT NODE]
:Last Action Node;
stop
@enduml
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes I ended using the new PlantUml's v2 activity grammar. Even if it's working fine for me right now, please note this still is a beta version. Also, I dont need Graphviz installed anymore.

Comment: I don't actually see any reference to the object node notation in the link you posted, but nonetheless, you solved my problem.

Comment: @MarkCh documentation seems to have changed, but if you look for `i := i + 1` you can still see an example of the object node (i.e. a simple rectangle).